# Is there a way to match every letter in a string and insert a specific letter in their place?

Tags: javascript

For example if I had the string "GCG", I'd like to insert a 
"C" at every "G" match, and a "G" at every "C" match, making it GCCGGC.

So far I have the following, but it prints GCGCGC.

```
function pairElement(str) {
    for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if(str[i] == "G") {
            return str.replace(/([GC+/])/g, "GC");
        } else if (str[i] == "C") {
            return str.replace(/([?=CG+/])/g, "CG");
        }
    }
}

pairElement("GCG");
```

Edit: I think only the first if statement is executing and not running the else if. Are there any other methods I can use to search for different letters, not only one, and insert another letter depending on what the search for letter is?

Comment: I think you wanted to say replace G with GC and C with CG

Comment: Isn't that what I have up there...?

Comment: The description was poor. You can use string.replace() to solve this. You don't need to split and join

Comment: Hey, I'm still learning! Be nice. Didn't mean offense with comment.

Comment: Didn't mean any offence, but it should've been  "I'd like to insert a "C" after every "G" match, and a "G" after every "C"". "At" signifies that you want to replace C with G and G with C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the `string` into `array` using `split`and then iterate through the array and replace each character.
Then you can use `join` to convert the array into string.

```js
var string = 'GCG';
var str = string.split('').map(c => {
  if(c === 'G') c = 'GC';
  else if (c === 'C') c = 'CG';
  return c;
}).join('');

console.log('String ' + string);
console.log('New String ' + str);
```

Comment: Great answer. I actually thought of using map before but wasn't getting it right. Also, it's essentially what I had been doing with the for loop, but did not it not work because the for loop escapes the function after fulfilling the first if, whereas the map function executes on all elements and therefore runs on both if statements...? Sorry if that's a dumb question, I'm new to this

Comment: For loop will also work.. but you are updating the value of `str` and you are running loop to its length. If you take a new string and change it's value. The for loop will work for it too.

Comment: I'm having some trouble seeing how that would look in code. Could you show me?

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```js
function pairElement(str) {
    return str.replace(/G|C/g, e => e=='G'?'GC':'CG')
}

console.log(pairElement("GCG"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using recursion. Once it hits the return statement, the control exits. A better way would be to use regex as one of the answers suggested but if you want to just make tiny modifications in your own code, maybe try something like this.

```
function pairElement(str) {
var newStr= ""; // using new string to make it more readible
    for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if(str[i] == "G") {
            newStr = newStr + str[i] + "C";
        } else if (str[i] == "C") {
            newStr = newStr + str[i] + "G";
        } else {
            newStr = newStr + str[i]; //you didn't specify what do you want to do in this case
        }
    }
    return newStr;
}

pairElement("GCG");
```